# ext js change color of panel to gradient

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I am trying to change the colors of all the items in my first ExtJS6 project.
Preferably I'd like to create some gradients for things such as panel backgrounds and the like.

Can someone please show me how to accomplish this?

I'm am looking at this post from 2009 but it just shows single colors, it might be outdated, and I don't know where to add lines to css in my project?

```
Two ways: 

First(Directly change in panel):
new Ext.Panel({
width:200,
height:200,
bodyStyle:{"background-color":"red"}, 
renderTo: document.body
});

Second(Add CSS class and use it in Panel's 'bodyCssClass' property): 
.x-panel-body{
background-color: blue}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe that if you want to

> change the colors of all the items in my first ExtJS6 project

its actually much better to build custom theme for your application and keep the advantages of the framework, for example pre-rendered images for legacy browsers.

Check this [ExtJS theming guide](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/core_concepts/theming.html).

Comment: You can, you don't have to, see my answer

Comment: Ok, I dont have to, its just better way. Because it is easier and more reliable and allows you to get the advantages of the framework that your method throws away, for example pre-rendered images for legacy browsers. _Also, I do not know why you compare your method and mine, they both work and my goal is to help the author so I told about an alternate approach._

Comment: I'm looking at the ExtJS theming guide, it states... “. Create a new folder / file: “packages/local/my-classic-theme/sass/var/Component.scss”. Add the following code to the Component.scss file:.      I don't have this folder... do you know where it is on a universal app?

Comment: @solarissf, if you correctly build custom theme package (read "Generating the Custom Theme Package and File Structure" part of the guide) path exactly the same as it is written - "your_workspace/packages/local/my-classic-theme/sass/var/Component.scss". _Also I've updated link to ExtJS 6 guide (instead of ExtJS 5), check it, but actually there is no major changes._

Comment: Yes it is the better way, it's not the simpler way though, not everyone chooses to use Sencha Command

Comment: @JuanMendes, if you have to change appearance of few components its easier to add some custom css rules, if you have to change appearance of all components its easier to build theme. _Actually first time I used Secnha CMD just to build custom theme and add it to my existing project, it was quite fast and easy._

Comment: @sergey exactly my point, if you're comfortable with adding build tools to your system, it works great. Some just choose not to for simpler projects

Answer (score 0):

[`bodyStyle`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-bodyStyle) lets you set CSS properties like [`background-image`](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/). This will apply to a single widget.

```
new Ext.Panel({
  width:200,
  height:200,
  bodyStyle:{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(red, orange);'}, 
  renderTo: document.body
});
```

If you want it to apply to all panels, you add the CSS after Ext's CSS

```
.x-panel-body{
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}
```

If you want it to apply to a set of panels, add a `cls` config and a matching CSS rule

```
.my-special-bg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, orange);
}

new Ext.Panel({
  width:200,
  height:200,
  cls: 'my-special-bg', 
  renderTo: document.body
});
```

Comment: you stated to add the CSS after Ext's CSS, where exactly is that file that I add to?  This project is a standard universal app

Comment: do you know where the file is to add the CSS on extjs6 universal?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, create your own CSS file, custom-ext.css and link to it from your HTML